# import statement mess in python

Tags: python, import, using-statement

I want to have a number of files imported in a general python file and then include that file when I need the imported modules in the current module. This of course will lead to errors and re-imports if using the from x import y, however when using the "normal" import statement I end up with long instruction statements, for example:

```
x = importModule.directoryName1.directoryName2.moduleName.ClassName()
```

whereas I'd like to do the following:

```
x = importModule.ClassName()
```

but as I said before, doing this:

```
from importModule.directoryName1.directoryName2.moduleNam import ClassName
```

in a general file doesn't work since I include importModule in ClassName.

So, I'm basically wondering if there's anyway around this (something like an using statement, such as the one in C++, perhaps?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've got recursive imports (`importModule` refers to `moduleName`, and `moduleName` refers to `importModule`.  If you refactor, you should be able to use

```
from importModule.directoryName1.directoryName2.moduleName import ClassName
```

To refactor, you can change the order in which things are imported in `moduleName` so that the class definition of `ClassName` occurs before the `importModule` import; as long as each file defines the references needed by the other module before they try and import the other module, things will work out.

Another way to refactor: you could always import `ClassName` within the function where it's used; as long as the function isn't called before `moduleName` is imported, you'll be fine.

**The best way** to refactor, though, is to move some classes or references into their own module, so you don't have any situation where `A` imports `B` *and* `B` imports `A`.  That will fix your problem, as well as make it easier to maintain things going forward.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *could* do

```
from importModule.directoryName1.directoryName2 import moduleName as importModule
```

but that's kind of ugly and very confusing, and won't score you a lot of points with the Python programmers who read your code later.

Comment: Doesn't work if you want to import from `moduleName` and `module2Name` in the same file.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `import importModule.directoryName1.directoryName2.moduleName as importModule`?